# Installing OpenLDAP on Fedora 12: ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Tags: fedora, installation, openldap

I've been trying to set up the OpenLDAP installed by default on Fedora 12, very unsuccessfully. My ultimate goal is to use LDAP authentication for user login and Apache, using the OpenLDAP server running on the same machine.

The server is running, but the error I always get when I try to use ldapsearch or ldapadd is: **ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)**

I've been following these tutorials, but none of them helped me:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/openldap_fedora7
- http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/ref-guide/s1-ldap-quickstart.html
- http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_ldap_authentication
- http://docs.fedoraproject.org/deployment-guide/f12/en-US/html/s1-ldap-pam.html
- http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html

First, some components were already installed, and I installed these with yum:

```
yum install openldap-servers openldap-devel
```

Then, I created a basic slapd.conf file in /etc/openldap:

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=sniejana-sandbox,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=root,dc=sniejana-sandbox,dc=com"
rootpw          {SSHA}cxdz55ygPu4T3ykg7dgu+L0VRvsFSeom
directory       /var/lib/ldap/sniejana-sandbox.com
```

I obtained the rootpw with this command:

```
slappasswd -s changeme
```

I also created the `/var/lib/ldap/sniejana-sandbox.com` directory and made sure the entire contents of `/var/lib/ldap` were owned by the ldap user.

I found two ldap.conf files, one in /etc and one in /etc/openldap. I don't know which is the right one. If I understood correctly, this file is to configure the client. I put this in both:

```
HOST localhost
BASE dc=sniejana-sandbox,dc=com
```

I then ran the server with:

```
service slapd start
```

It said OK.

Most of the tutorials above say to use the command `ldapsearch -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" -W` to ensure that everything's working. When I execute this command, a password prompt appears, and after entering the password, I get the error.

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=root,dc=sniejana-sandbox,dc=com" -W
Enter LDAP password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

The same thing happens when trying to use ldapadd. I tried with an encrypted and unencrypted password in slapd.conf, it doesn't change anything. Adding a -x for simple authentication doesn't change anything either.

netstat -ap confirms the server is listening:

```
tcp   0   0 *:ldap    *:*       LISTEN      4148/slapd          
tcp   0   0 *:ldap    *:*       LISTEN      4148/slapd
```

ps -ef|grep slapd confirms the process is running:

```
ldap   4148  1  0 15:22 ?   00:00:00 /usr/sbin/slapd -h  ldap:/// -u ldap
```

Running slaptest procudes *config file testing succeeded*.

I read somewhere that the command `ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContext` can confirm the server is running. It appears to work:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: namingContext 
#

#
dn:

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

I'm running out of ideas. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! My problem is solved! I just need to delete the directory using `rm -rf /etc/openldap/slapd.d`. This will force OpenLDAP to look for my `slapd.conf` file while starting the service.

Comment: Indeed, that works. Removing /etc/openldap/slapd.d causes openldap to load /etc/openldap/slapd.conf. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need remove a /etc/openldap/slapd.d directory, but you can add as parameter for `slapd` `-f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

i have this openldap problem in Fedora 12 too!
But if u try start your openldap manually using following command, it behaviour turn to normal.
     /usr/sbin/slapd -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf

I suspect the default command (i am referring to "service slapd start") is not loading the openldap config file (i am referring to /etc/openldap/slapd.conf) which i create manually after those yum installation.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem when i tried this first time.

After an analysis, I just removed the `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/` directory and also deleted the contents of the `/var/lib/ldap/` directory (which contains the database). After that everything works fine.

Note : `var/lib/ldap` directory must exist, or else the `slapd` service will never start.

I understood this by reading the `/etc/init.d/slapd` script. In that script, they blindly checking whether the `/etc/openldap/slapd.d` directory exist or not. If yes means, they simply ignored the `slapd.conf` file. That script also checks whether database exist in `/var/lib/ldap/` directory. If yes means, they use that database else they create a new empty database.

`/etc/openldap/slapd.d` directory is exactly contains the configuration information in a directory data structure which is used instead of `slapd.conf` file. I guess, Fedora uses this directory by default.